# Parsing JSON to not objects in .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, json, .net-4.0

Is there a JSON parser for .NET 4.0?

---

Ideally something like:

```
String jsonText = GetTheJsonFromTheInternet();
var json = JsonValue.Parse(jsonText);
```

and now i have a nested set of key-value pairs.

## Use JSON.net

What i *dont* want, is to have to create a set of objects to match the JSON. i asking about **parsing** JSON, not **deserializing** JSON. You can pretend it's because i don't know the structure of the JSON.

Similar to how you parse XML:

```
String xmlText = GetTheXmlFromTheInternet();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(XmlText);
```

and now i have a nested set of names-values-attributes. You don't create objects to represent the XML DOM tree; you parse a string of XML and now it's easy to navigate and find things.

## Why not just use JsonValue.Parse()?

Because:

- [JsonValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonvalue.aspx) (found in `System.Json.dll`) was not available until .NET Framework 4.5.
- and Visual Studio 2010 cannot target .NET Framework 4.5. (only Visual Studio 2012)
- and Visual Studio 2012 requires Windows 8

And writing my own JSON parser would take a few days (to get it correct and good).

i've gone through the [JSON.net documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/). i can't tell if it supports JSON parsing.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 runs fine on Windows 7.

Comment: From what I understand of your question, I think you want to parse the JSON to a dictionary instead?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 doesn't require Win8, I've been running it just fine on Win7

Comment: Before I answer, any reason why [`JObject.Parse` does not work for you](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm)?

Comment: This is not directly in answer to your question, but Visual Studio 2012 is compatible with Windows 7 and Windows XP (see [Visual Studio 2012 Platform compatibility and system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility)).

Comment: This question seem really really hostile.

Comment: @curtisk Sorry; i was referring to the *Express* edition of Visual Studio 2012. (*"**Setup Blocked**. This product can only be installed on a computer with Windows 8 or later."*)

Comment: @sixlettervariables It does work about it; when i learn(ed) of it.

Comment: @Ramhound That's my secret; i'm always hostile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with JSON.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330747/parsing-json-with-json-net)

Comment: You can't be hostile.  You're Canadian.  :-)

Comment: @IanBoyd - Its good your hostile gives me a valid reason to give you negative reputation for this hostile question.

Comment: @Ramhound If you like hostility, you'll love [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104850/c-test-if-string-is-a-guid-without-throwing-exceptions), where i also try to push people into answering the question that was asked.

Comment: The question only seems hostile because people that ask questions on SO are sick and tired of either getting a "you're stupid, use this thing" response or having their questions constantly closed as duplicates of something else that actually has nothing at all to do with the issue.  It's to the point where you have to not only phrase your question, you also have to supply a long list of reasons why you're not using something else or why it's not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. It will return either `JObject` or `JArray`. You can use all Linq tricks on them.

You can also assign the result of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to `dynamic` and use duck typing

Some examples:

- [Deserialize json with Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517734/deserialize-json-with-json-net/16518068#16518068)
- [Parsing JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378829/parsing-jsonobject/16383300#16383300)

## Example

```cs
String jsonText = 
    @"{
        ""files"":[{
            ""url"":""http://us.battle.net/auction-data/x/auctions.json"",
            ""lastModified"":1369051860000
        }]
    }";

JToken data = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

String url = (String)data["files"][0]["url"];
Int64 lastModified = (Int64)data["files"][0]["lastModified"];
```

Comment: @sixlettervariables yes if you are sure it is not an array. using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is safer